# AWS ECS - a free way for passing secrets

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs, credentials

I've got simple app as AWS ECS. 
Now I want to integrate it with database (AWS RDS).

The problem is - I need to pass the RDS credentials to my docker image, eg. as environment variable in a secure way.

After some research, I found two ways:
- AWS Secrets Manager
- AWS System Manager Parameter Store

But... both of them are paid.

1. Secrets Manager costs 0.40$/month for 1 secret.
2. System Manager Parameter Store requires 'Customer Managed Key' which also costs 1$/month.

As a Free Tier User, for my simple app, I would rather not to pay for ONLY 'storing secrets'. So... Is there any other secure and recommended way to pass sensitive data to docker application hosted on ECS ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> System Manager Parameter Store requires 'Customer Managed Key' which also costs 1$/month.

This is not the case. This is only required if you want to use your own CMK. If not, then you can use **default CMK** [provided](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/parameter-store-about-examples.html) by the AWS which is **free**:

> SecureString data is encrypted and decrypted using a AWS Key Management Service (KMS) key. You can use either a **default KMS key provided by AWS** or create and use your own customer master key (CMK).

Also in the free tier, you have 20,000 api requests each [month](https://aws.amazon.com/kms/):

> AWS Free Tier includes **20,000 free** AWS Key Management Service requests each month.